# fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found - Qt 5.14 Preview Android

Tags: android, qt

I’m giving a try to Qt 5.14 Preview on Android and when compiling an existing project I’m having this:

In file included from /Qt/5.14.0/android/include/QtGui/QGuiApplication:1:
In file included from /Qt/5.14.0/android/include/QtGui/qguiapplication.h:43:
In file included from /Qt/5.14.0/android/include/QtGui/qtguiglobal.h:43:
**/Qt/5.14.0/android/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:45:12: fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found**

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Which Android NDK are you using? See also https://forum.qt.io/topic/98006/fatal-error-type_traits-file-not-found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I upgraded NDK to ndk/20.1.5948944 and now works fine.

Comment: I can confirm that. Qt 5.14 requires ndk-r20b